# Malformed certificate in oracle java8

Tags: ubuntu

I installed oracle java 8 JDK and tried to run sdkmanager command line. This is what I get

```
# tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools:27.0.3" "platforms:android-25"
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Certinomis_-_Autorit??_Racine.crt
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.toPath(FileSystemFileOp.java:284)
    at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.isDirectory(FileSystemFileOp.java:169)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:225)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:201)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:123)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:517)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:397)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:364)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:718)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:295)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:118)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:93)
```

How shall I fix this malformed cert issue?

Comment: This is not an issue with the JRE certificates -> the jdk stores the certificates as part of the JRE distribution in a single file called 'cacerts'. This certificate is part of teh OS certificates and it seems that your process is not UTF capable (are the right env vars set ?) - the ?? are the letter e with a tick (é)

Comment: Looks like there is a non printable character in the file name: `Autorit??_`

Comment: - Certinomis - AutoritÃ© Racine, expires Sep 17 08:28:59 2028 GMT (Certinomis_-_AutoritÃ©_Racine.crt), according to http://www.myigel.biz/public/IGEL_UNIVERSAL_DESKTOP_FIRMWARE/LX/V5/lx_5.08.100_CA-certificates.txt?forcedownload.

so what locale is that??

Comment: Just a guess: Android JDK is different to Oracle one. Probably right now failure happens on JCE difference.

Comment: Just rename your file to something using only ASCII characters and be done with. You do not want that important file name be dependent on a locale or character set in a target environment you might not be able to control. Don't make a simple thing complicated.

Answer (score 1):

surprisingly the solution is very simple

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I had this problem in docker image/dockerfile, and the approach is the same. Just add:

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8